# How to make the textlayout not go beyond the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

**How to make the textlayout not go beyond the screen**

I have a program where I need to add line breaks to the `textlayout`, but when I add `\n` to it a certain number of times, **the text goes beyond the screen**. So here's how to fix it?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:hint="Command"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"></EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="657dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="↲"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="658dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add the layout code, I think you might have width/height wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use match_parent or wrap_content or you can use 0dp to scale view based to constraints. I would recommend use 0dp for width(scale to your requirement) and wrap_cotent for width